# How do I access certain values in this struct

Tags: json, go

I am logging something in Go. Here is the value and below that is the result when I log reflect.TypeOf(attributes.Pdp.SellableUnits[i].Attributes):

```
[{22555278 val 03.5}]
[{22554867 val 04.0}]
[{22555002 val 04.5}]
[{22555279 val 05.0}]
[{22555280 val 05.5}]
[{22555144 val 06.0}]
[{22555145 val 06.5}]
[{22555146 val 07.0}]

// TypeOf
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
[1]struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\"" }
```

I want to be able to log the ID string only, in this case being the string of many numbers at the top of the code block (22555278, 22554867, 22555002, etc...)

Here is my code to log all of this

```
// Struct
type sizeJ struct {
    Pdp struct {
        Units []struct {
            Attributes [1]struct {
                ID    string `json:"id"`
                Type  string `json:"type"`
                Value string `json:"value"`
            } `json:"attributes"`
        } `json:"Units"`
    } `json:"pdp"`
}

// ...
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

        xml := strings.NewReader(string(body))

        j, _ := xj.Convert(xml)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        var attributes sizeJ
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(j.String()), &attributes)

        for i := 0; i < len(attributes.Pdp.Units); i++ {
            fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(attributes.Pdp.Units[i].Attributes))

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type is declared as:

```
type sizeJ struct {
    Pdp struct {
        Units []struct {
            Attributes [1]struct {
                ID    string `json:"id"`
                Type  string `json:"type"`
                Value string `json:"value"`
            } `json:"attributes"`
        } `json:"Units"`
    } `json:"pdp"`
}
```

You can print just the ID's:

```
for i := 0; i < len(attributes.Pdp.Units); i++ {
    // fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(attributes.Pdp.Units[i].Attributes))
    fmt.Printf("ID: %s\n", attributes.Pdp.Units[i].Attributes[0].ID)

}
```

Comment: attributes.Pdp.SellableUnits[i].Attributes.ID undefined (type [1]struct{ID string "json:\"id\""; Type string "json:\"type\""; Value string "json:\"value\""} has no field or method ID)

Comment: Added my struct to main post as well